# logout issue faceing in twitter api

Tags: android, twitter

i am login in my application `throw twitter`. it works fine.

when i am going to logout from my application. it will logout perfectly.
But problem comes when i am going to **login again** throw twitter.

its login already. now how to `clear session`.

please help me out.

```
public void resetAccessToken() 
    {
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_KEY, null);
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY, null);
        editor.putString(TWEET_USER_NAME, null);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

after reset acces token i can not get this screen again. i am getting already logedin screen.

[image]

Comment: remove Cookie and clear Cache from web View .

Comment: @NaveenKumar can you elborate more

Answer (score 1):

You're using Twitter to log into your application. This means that if you're logged into Twitter (have a valid Twitter session cookie), then you're logged into your application.

If you log out of Twitter itself, then try to access your application, you will encounter the login screen again.

Also, if you manually remove the Twitter session cookie from your browser's cookie jar, and try to access your application, you will encounter the login screen.